# Generate JSON for Google Charts using PHP

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I'm following the guide at: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

They give a json snippet for a json example. How do yo build this one with php? Usually there is just converting arrays to json using json_encode() but this time it seems like you need an object aswell. Can anyone clarify this?

The json snippet:

```
{
  "cols": [
    {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
  ],
  "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
  ]
}
```

What I have so far:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->cols= array(
    array("id"=>"", "label"=>"Topping", "pattern"=>"", "type"=>"string"), 
    array("id"=>"", "label"=>"Slices", "pattern"=>"", "type"=>"string"));
$obj->rows = array(
    array()
);

echo json_encode($obj);
```

Is there anyone that knows how to complete this php representation?

Edit: 
My echo outputs:

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"string"}],"rows":[[]]}
```

Comment: so what does your code echo as result?

Comment: PHP associative arrays will convert to JSON objects, you do not need `stdClass`

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer, sorry. I've updated the question and inserted my output

Comment: @ndm, so what structure would you use on the arrays?

Comment: the same structure as the JSON... see http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: What is the question now exactly? Why not just go on, like you did the first part?

Comment: @NDM There is no reason why you would not use `stdClass` though if you wanted to make your code self documenting

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer I dont know how to proceed. I'm trying alot of different versions in order to keep the exact same syntax. I just thought someone would know this well, to show me how this json could be remade using php

Comment: he's using both `stdClass` and associative arrays, so if anything, it's more confusing.

Comment: Can someone write an answer and write it as it should be done (in a non-confusing way). So I can see and understand why mine is wrong?

Comment: @NDM there you have a point

Comment: So if this is bad, how would it look like using only associative arrays or stdClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
<?php
$obj = array("cols"=>array(
    array("id"=>"", "label"=>"Topping", "pattern"=>"", "type"=>"string"), 
    array("id"=>"", "label"=>"Slices", "pattern"=>"", "type"=>"string")),
    "rows"=>array(
    array("c"=>array(array("v"=>"Mushrooms", "f"=>null), array("v"=>3, "f"=>null))),
    array("c"=>array(array("v"=>"Onions", "f"=>null), array("v"=>1, "f"=>null))),
    array("c"=>array(array("v"=>"Olives", "f"=>null), array("v"=>1, "f"=>null))),
    array("c"=>array(array("v"=>"Zucchini", "f"=>null), array("v"=>1, "f"=>null))),
    array("c"=>array(array("v"=>"Pepperoni", "f"=>null), array("v"=>2, "f"=>null))),
    )
);

echo json_encode($obj);
?>
```

Comment: I know, but he wanted a code, that just works for this specific problem and thats what i delivered. Have my point on your definitly more sophisticated answer.

Answer (score 2):

PHP associative arrays will converts to objects in JSON, so `stdClass` is not needed. You already got 80% of the structure so here are a few pointers:

```
$data = [
    'cols' => [],
    'rows' => [],
];
```

will result in :

```
{
    'cols': [],
    'rows': [],
}
```

In order to get JSON arrays, don't give keys to the values:

```
$data = [
    'c' => [
        [ // <- no key here
            'v' => 'Mushroom', 
            'f' => null
        ],
        [ // <- no key here
            'v' => '3', 
            'f' => null
        ],
    ],
    // ...
];
```

will give you a data row:

```
{
    "c": [ // <- we got an actual array here because there was no key
        {
            "v":"Mushrooms",
            "f":null
        },
        {
            "v":3,
            "f":null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ahh, now I know what you talk about. I didn't know I could use arrays this way. I thought each {} was needed to be an object. Upvoted!

Comment: I think you will have to wrap `null` in quote like `'null'` otherwise you get nothing in the output

Comment: no: if you wrap it in quotes you will get the string `'null'` in your JSON and not the null constant.